# Different sort/arrange preferences for different directories

Tags: filemanager

Is there a file manager that will let me sort/arrange various directories differently?

I want my downloads folder to be sorted by last modified, and other locations to follow alphabetical order.

I am on Xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

You can try [nnn](https://github.com/jarun/nnn). It supports the following sorts:

- modification/access/inode time
- file size
- file extension
- disk usage
- apparent disk usage
- version sort
- all the above in reverse order

Comment: looks like it is cli.

Comment: Yes it is, with excellent GUI integration out of the box. It works in all desktop environments and your default apps without the need to configure anything.

Note that while replying earlier, I didn't realize your question was GUI file manager specific.

Comment: But does `nnn` allow one folder to be always sorted by size and another to always be sorted by mod time? That's the core of the question, IMO. If `nnn` does have this feature, please make that clear in your answer.

Comment: There are multiple contexts which can have their own order (along with other settings). To persist the settings users can save their preference using sessions and the contexts will retain their sort order. nnn supports persistent sessions, so you can always start where you left and the order will persist. However, nnn doesn't store per-dir settings (it's per context instead) so the order will not change (like Windows Explorer) every time you visit the specific directory.